# Error: could not find a distribution template for Kali/kali-rolling

Tags: kali-linux, yubikey

Trying to follow [Enabling the Yubico PPA on Ubuntu : Yubico Support](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000010964-enabling-the-yubico-ppa-on-ubuntu), by executing:

> add-apt-repository ppa:yubico/stable && sudo apt-get update

yet, getting following message:

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:yubico/stable && sudo apt-get update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Kali/kali-rolling
#
```

Answer (score 3):

`add-apt-repository` doesn't appear to know how to deal with Kali. That's what this line says about it:

> aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Kali/kali-rolling

To add this you'll have to add the PPA by hand if you truly want to set this up. This means getting the appropriate sources. If you go to this URL you can use the pull down to get a rough idea of what the `/etc/apt/sources.list` entries look like for the different versions of Ubuntu:

- https://launchpad.net/~yubico/+archive/ubuntu/stable

For Ubuntu 18.10:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yubico/stable/ubuntu cosmic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yubico/stable/ubuntu cosmic main
```

For Kali you'll likely have to change these.

#### References

- [Thread: Adding new PPAs in Kali-Rolling 2017-2](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?37653-Adding-new-PPAs-in-Kali-Rolling-2017-2)
- [Setting Up 2-factor authentication on backtrack5 (or Kali) sshd with a Yubikey](http://garydewey.com/setting-up-2-factor-authentication-on-backtrack5-or-kali-sshd-with-a-yubikey/)

Comment: And then after following this advice, for this and other packages, OPs might hit on rpm post/pre-install scripts checking the distribution name and not knowing kali, dangling dependencies and/or things that won't automagically compile when installing, as  PPA for Ubuntu is being (ab)used. The better advice here is if you are not sysadmin/developer inclined, is to use Ubuntu PPAs in Ubuntu and not in Kali. Or asking for that feature on their forums, they *love* to mix different incompatible packages.