# Deepin 15.10 Error: could not find a distribution template for Deepin/stable

Tags: docker, repository, deepin, ppa

When I was trying to install Docker on Deepin 15.10 via package repository, I had this error:

`Error: could not find a distribution template for Deepin/stable`

Comment: Welcome! Answers should go into the separate Answer box, below. Thank you!

Comment: Please feel free to self-answer here; I've updated your Question to include only the question.  Please also take [our tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to become more familiar with how the site works. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: could not find a distribution template for Kali/kali-rolling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463763/error-could-not-find-a-distribution-template-for-kali-kali-rolling)

Answer (score 11):

Since the OP never moved their Answer out of the Question, here's what they had originally.

---

Since Deepin 15.10, the base kernel is Debian stable, but in the Deepin distribution template is set as unstable; let's change that.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Deepin.info
```

change

```
Suite: unstable
```

to

```
Suite: stable
```

and voilá, you now can add PPA without that problem above.

Comment: This was helpful

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add the repository manually.

Something like this:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

printf 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable\n' \
| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list
```

Comment: You are awesome! Tks!